# Close dropdown menu when clicking sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been having issues in trying to make this work.

I have this submenu, that I would like to click its sibling ul, when I click in its sibling.

I have researched here and tried couple things to no avail.

this is what my code is looking like now, the toggle is working fine:

```
if ( $(window).width() < 740) { 
        $('.submenu').click(function(e){
             e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var el = (e.target || e.srcElement);
            var $this = $(this);

            $(el).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
            $(el).siblings('ul').addClass('activeState');
            if( $this.siblings().hasClass('activeState')){
                $this.slideUp();
            }
            $(el).find('span').toggleClass('bg-arrow-down bg-arrow-up');
        });
    }
```

and this is more or less, what my HTML looks like. it has various submenus, and these are the menus that I am trying to make it work.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- <div class="nav-item-container"> -->
                <div class="panel-heading head-category">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <span><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Products</a></span>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuPanelListGroup">
                                <i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group collapse out" id="menuPanelListGroup">
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuPanelSubListGroup">
                            <span>Item 1</span>
                            <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="menuPanelSubListGroup" class="collapse children-list-sublink">
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span>SubItem 2</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span>SubItem 3</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 2</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 3</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 4</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 5</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <!-- </div> -->

            <!-- <div class="nav-item-container"> -->
                <div class="panel-heading head-category">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <span><a href="#">Latin Markets</a></span>              
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu2PanelListGroup">
                            <i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group collapse out" id="menu2PanelListGroup">
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu2PanelSubListGroup">
                            <span>Item 1</span>
                            <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="menu2PanelSubListGroup" class="collapse children-list-sublink">
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span>SubItem 2</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span>SubItem 3</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 2</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 3</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 4</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 5</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <!-- </div> -->

            <!-- <div class="nav-item-container"> -->
                <div class="panel-heading head-category">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <span><a href="#">Shows</a></span>
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tradeshowPanelListGroup">
                                <i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group collapse out" id="tradeshowPanelListGroup">
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tradeshowPanelSubListGroup">
                            <span>Item 1</span>
                            <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="tradeshowPanelSubListGroup" class="collapse children-list-sublink">
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span>SubItem 2</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                                <span>SubItem 3</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 2</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 3</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 4</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
                        <span>Item 5</span>
                        <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Just that if statement is not working.

Comment: You don't have an element called `$('.submenu')`

Comment: Thanks Michael, I do have... just not on the example that I pasted. my mistake.

Comment: Are you going to update your post? Read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for that. I will make sure to read it and make the necessary improvements on my next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you're not seeing that happen -- if you are taking window width to be window width, it may or may not be. Code below is working fine, and I've added a maxWidth value rather than hard-coding the 740 you were using.

I guess the question is, what are you trying to accomplish? When the width is over 740, style it differently? Maybe you want to look at CSS media types?

So you asked about toggling classes. The issue is, the right/down arrows are on a descendant of the clicked node. I've made it work, see below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // set a default minimum width
  var minWidth = 740;
  // Is the viewport no wider than my min?
  if ($(window).width() < minWidth) {
    // If so, go ahead and hide all submenus
    var myMenu = $(".panel");
    myMenu.find("li:has('ul')").on("click", function(evt) {
      // click on any LI that contains
      //  nested UL's, show the child ul
      //  and hide all of this LI's sibling's
      //  children's nested ULs.
      evt.preventDefault();
      evt.stopPropagation();

      $(this).children("span")
        .toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon--chevron-right")
        .toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();

      $(this).siblings(":has(ul:visible)")
        .children("span")
        .toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon--chevron-right")
        .toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
      $(this).siblings().find("ul:visible").slideUp();

    }).prepend("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'>").children("ul").hide();
    // The above line actually hides all the nested
    //  ULs initially.
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <!-- <div class="nav-item-container"> -->
  <ul>
    <li class="panel-title panel-heading head-category">
      <span><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Products</a></span>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuPanelListGroup">
        <i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="list-group collapse out" id="menuPanelListGroup">
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuPanelSubListGroup">
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
          </a>

          <ul id="menuPanelSubListGroup" class="collapse children-list-sublink">
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span>SubItem 2</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span>SubItem 3</span>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 2</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 3</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 4</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 5</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </li>

    <li class="panel-title panel-heading head-category">
      <span><a href="#">Latin Markets</a></span>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu2PanelListGroup">
        <i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="list-group collapse out" id="menu2PanelListGroup">
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu2PanelSubListGroup">
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
          </a>

          <ul id="menu2PanelSubListGroup" class="collapse children-list-sublink">
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span>SubItem 2</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span>SubItem 3</span>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 2</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 3</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 4</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 5</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </li>


    <li class="panel-title panel-heading head-category">
      <span><a href="#">Shows</a></span>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tradeshowPanelListGroup">
        <i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="list-group collapse out" id="tradeshowPanelListGroup">
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tradeshowPanelSubListGroup">
            <span>Item 1</span>
            <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
          </a>

          <ul id="tradeshowPanelSubListGroup" class="collapse children-list-sublink">
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span><a href="#">SubItem 1</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span>SubItem 2</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
              <span>SubItem 3</span>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 2</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 3</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 4</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item children-list-group">
          <span>Item 5</span>
          <b class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Snowmonkey, yes, the style about 740px, is different, the menus float to the right. but you fixed the code a bit, so I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Minimal changes to the HTML -- rather than using top-level divs and nested ULs, everything becomes ULs and LIs. As to the JS, I changed it so that it doesn't care what level it's at, the code is consistent with all LIs with nested ULs. The reason I suggested the CSS alternative, I'm a huge fan of Eric Meyer's work with CSS. Take a look at http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/menus/demo.html for nested menus, purely using CSS.

Comment: Your solution worked great, thanks for the help. I will take a look on Eric Meyer's post, I already use his reset, so I am a big fan as well. I have been trying to do as much as I can with CSS, but since I am working with a big codebase, sometimes is difficult, plus I am just starting out.

Comment: also, do you now I can change that toggle direction the ul:visible sibling? I thought something like this would work, but no... $(this).siblings().find("ul:visible span").toggleClass('bg-arrow-down bg-arrow-up');

Comment: Issue is, the span doesn't necessarily exist. I've added code to prepend the span to every sub-menu-containing element, and then the toggle happens as expected. See above.

Comment: Hope it helps, best of luck!